# Reducing solutions of Sin[2t] Sin[t] == Cos[t] to a simpler form

Tags: equation-solving, trigonometry

I evaluated

```
Solve[Sin[2 t] Sin[t] == Cos[t] && 0 <= t < 2 Pi, t]
```

And got these results.

> ```
> {{t -> π/2}, {t -> (3 π)/2}, {t -> -2 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]]}, 
>  {t -> 2 π + 2 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]]}, {t -> 2 π - 2 ArcTan[1 + Sqrt[2]]}, 
>  {t -> 2 ArcTan[1 + Sqrt[2]]}}
> ```

Now, by hand, the exact answers are $\pi/2$, $3\pi/2$, $\pi/4$, $3\pi/4$, $5\pi/4$, and $7\pi/4$. I did some proof and showed that $-2\tan^{-1}(1-\sqrt2)=\pi/4$, but I am wondering if there is an easy way to convert the answer given by *Mathematica* to the exact answers found by hand.

Comment: Most directly: `FullSimplify[results]`.

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`FullSimplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html) is what you are looking for.

```
Solve[Sin[2 t] Sin[t] == Cos[t] && 0 <= t < 2 Pi, t] // FullSimplify
```

> {{t -> π/2}, {t -> (3 π)/2}, {t -> π/4}, {t -> (7 π)/4}, 
>        {t -> (5 π)/4}, {t -> (3 π)/4}}

Comment: My goodness. Why didn't I try that? I tried other things, but not that. I've got to train myself to do Simplify, then FullSimplify if that doesn't work. Thanks for the help. This will help in class tonight.